# how do I convert str postfixed with 'Z' to dateTime structure?

Tags: rust

According to this [RFC](https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-rfcs/tree/master/features/0095-basic-message), `sent_time` is in ISO 8601 UTC format. Based on that info I should be able to use `DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339` to parse `sent_time` into a `DateTime` struct, per the [docs](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.parse_from_rfc3339).

However, using the value of `sent_time` in the example in the RFC, I get an error. This line of code

```
let dt = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339("2019-01-15 18:42:01Z").unwrap_err();
```

Produces this output if I `println!` it

```
`"input contains invalid characters"`
```

I have tried using both `DateTime::parse_from_str` and `NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str`, both of which return the same error: eg this line of code

```
let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2019-01-15 18:42:01Z", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").unwrap_err();
```

produces if I `println!` it

```
"trailing input"
```

I do not see any documentation about [`DateTime` string formatting](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.13/chrono/format/strftime/index.html) which allows for time to formatted like the example above. Perhaps I have missed reading it.

If I have understood the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) correct, `sent_time` example is correctly formatted date time string. Does this seem accurate?

If so, how can I parse it to `DateTime` struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaiveDateTime` with format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ` works, notice you need to add the literal `Z` at the end of format to match your string:

```
let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2019-01-15 18:42:01Z", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ");
println!("{:?}", dt);
// Ok(2019-01-15T18:42:01)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aeb5319b30dce0dcf4622cb3a1f2739d).

Comment: These days you could probably get away with `DateTime<Utc>` which should understand the trailing Z.